# Find current result's position in Mysql

Tags: mysql

My query:

SELECT videoid FROM related_videos WHERE videoid='$current_page_video_id' order by videoid desc;

Result return:
1) videoid = 135;
2) videoid = 126;
3) videoid = 113;
4) videoid = 95;
5) videoid = 32;
6) videoid = 19;
7) videoid = 13; (How to get to know the position is No.7?)
8) videoid = 9;
9) videoid = 6;

Let say my current_page_video_id is 13, how can i find the position of this videoid(13) in the above query?

Comment: First answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3149861/mysql-how-to-get-a-sequential-number-with-rows shows how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM related_videos WHERE videoid >= 13
```